# Adding permissions to django-allauth's OAuth token

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-allauth

When using django-allauth, the OAuth handshake with various social services is handed automatically.  Where in this process do you add privileges to the OAtuh token that is returned?

For example, when using allauth with GitHub, the login prompt on GitHub is only for "Grants read-only access to public information", which is the default and minimum level of access.  How do I pass additional [scopes](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#parameters) to the OAuth handshake managed by allauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allauth lets you pass extra parameters to the auth handshake using the `AUTH_PARAMS` key in the settings of a social account provider.  For example, put the following in your settings.py to add the repo scope to the returned GitHub token:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "github": {
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {"scope": "repo"}
    },
}
```